# Class hierarchy - who should talk to whom?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on a game project that incorporates Core Data and I want to have the code as modular as possible.

Right now my Core Data "hierarchy" chain looks like this:

Core Data Entities -> SaveGame Class -> GameLogic class -> Receiver

The SaveGame class handles everything related to Core Data, such as the managedObjectContext, various entities, saving and overwriting operations etc.

The GameLogic class handels game mechanics and does a few things with the Data passed from Core Data, such as calculate income, the current amound of money, handle level changes etc.

I'm not happy with this setup though for one reason: If the Receiver (such as the HUD) asks for a data from Core Data that data then has to be passed along that chain resulting in a lot of one-liners that do pretty much nothing, like this:

```
+(NSArray *)passCoreDataInfo
{
return [CoreDataEntity fetchCoreDataEntityInfo] // ExecuteFetchRequest
}
```

which would then be used like this in a class lower in the hierarchy:

```
+(NSArray *)passCoreDataInfoAgain
{
return [HigherClass passCoreDataInfo]
}
```

until somewhere down the chain my Receiver does something useful with it:

```
(...)
NSArray *coreDataInfo = [SomeClass passCoreDataInfoYetAgain];
(...)
```

This probably wastes a lot of memory and processing power, but I also don't want to give in to the dreaded "everybody talking to everybody" model.

Can you guys give me and tips on how to set up y hiararchy better and get around this passing on and on of the same data?

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the Receivers subscribe for (generic) messages sent from the CoreDataEntities?  Not so much an "everybody talking to everybody" model, but a "everybody can follow tweets of those they're interested in" model.

Comment: That'll work for 'push' messaging, i.e. the CoreDataEntities 'tweets' about any update to other objects that follow it. But the OP asks for 'pull' messaging, i.e. the other objects ask for the latest data from CoreDataEntities, thus those objects might not be interested to get all the 'tweets' from latter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a shared instance, just like `[CCDirector sharedDirector]`, `[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]`, `[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache]`, `[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]` etc?

Just name it `[CoreDataEntity sharedEntity]` or something:

```
static CoreDataEntity *instanceOfCoreDataEntity = nil;

@implementation CoreDataEntity

+ (CoreDataEntity *)sharedEntity {
    if (!instanceOfCoreDataEntity) {
        instanceOfCoreDataEntity = [[CoreDataEntity alloc] initWithSomething:@"something"];
    }
    return instanceOfCoreDataEntity;
}

....
```

Then you can use it anywhere:

```
NSArray *coreDataInfo = [[CoreDataEntity sharedEntity] passCoreDataInfo];
```